# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for with has_one association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm having an issue accepting nested attributes with a has_one relationship.

Here are my models:

```
class User
  has_one :shipping_address

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address
end

class ShippingAddress
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and view:

```
<%= form_for @user %>
  <%= f.fields_for @user.shipping_address do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.text_field :address %>
    ....
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass
```

I know this is telling me that @user.shipping_address is nil, but I can't figure out why. I'm also not able to do this:

```
@user.shipping_address.create(address: 'something')
```

Because @user.shipping_address is nil. I know I should be able to do this if the association is set up correctly, but I can't figure out why it's not.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That's your entire user.rb? You didn't notice that you're missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address`? And did you add `shipping_address_attributes` to your strong params?

Comment: Sorry, that's just an over simplification of my user.rb.  I'll update it.

Comment: And I'm not even able to get to the point where I'm submitting the form. It won't build the ShippingAddress object.

Comment: Posting incomplete code and then asking people "Any thoughts?" is completely useless.

Comment: Come on, I simply forgot add that line of code.

Comment: With `has_one` it would be something like `@user.create_shipping_address(...)`. Doesn't answer your original question, but, does address part of it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build shipping address object in your controller before rendering the form:

```
# Your current assignment
@user = User.where(...)
# Add this line:
@user.build_shipping_address
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, try this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :shipping_address do |builder| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This was returning nil because I hadn't built the association like the above answer suggested

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Not knowing all the details under the hood I explain it to myself like this.
You have started a form context with "form_for @user". So the User is already known inside of this context. You can access the nested structures with :shipping_address.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This was returning nil because I hadn't built the association like the above answer suggested.